# _.pick method to match the sub property in an objects array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using _.pick method in the following manner

suppose I have an array of strings which are nothing but property names I want to get from each object in array of objects

```
var wantedPropArray=["prop1","prop2","prop3.name"];
```

Below is my objects array

```
var objectArray = [
        {"prop1":"prop1Data1","prop2":"prop2Data1","prop3":{"name":"Tom","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data1","prop5":"prop5Data1"},
        {"prop1":"prop1Data2","prop2":"prop2Data2","prop3":{"name":"Cat","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data2","prop5":"prop5Data2"}
        {"prop1":"prop1Data3","prop2":"prop2Data3","prop3":{"name":"Tom","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data3","prop5":"prop5Data3"}
        {"prop1":"prop1Data4","prop2":"prop2Data4","prop3":{"name":"Tom","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data4","prop5":"prop5Data4"}
    ]
for( var item in objectArray ){          
    var objectArrayOnlySelectedProperties = _.pick(objectArray[item] , wantedPropArray);
}
```

suppose for first iteration lets see objectArrayOnlySelectedProperties  data,
I am getting

```
objectArrayOnlySelectedProperties = {"prop1":"prop1Data1","prop2":"prop2Data1"};
```

I am expecting it to give me the result something like this

```
objectArrayOnlySelectedProperties = {"prop1":"prop1Data1","prop2":"prop2Data1","prop3.name":"Tom"};
```

what i mean to say is _.pick method is not able to look into prop3 and get me prop3.name.
Can anyone suggest how to use underscores' pick method to match the sub properties of each object in an array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is not supported with underscorejs out of the box.  But there is this gist that offers the support as a mix-in:

https://gist.github.com/furf/3208381

Here is some code using the above gist to do what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/wHXCv/1/

```
_.mixin({
  deep: function (obj, key) {
    var keys = key.split('.'),
        i = 0,
        value = null,
        n = keys.length;

      while ((obj = obj[keys[i++]]) != null && i < n) {};
      value = i < n ? void 0 : obj;
      var result = {};
      result[key]=value;
      return result;
  }
});

var objectArray = [
                 {"prop1":"prop1Data1","prop2":"prop2Data1","prop3":{"name":"Tom","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data1","prop5":"prop5Data1"},
                 {"prop1":"prop1Data2","prop2":"prop2Data2","prop3":{"name":"Cat","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data2","prop5":"prop5Data2"},
                 {"prop1":"prop1Data3","prop2":"prop2Data3","prop3":{"name":"Tom","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data3","prop5":"prop5Data3"},
                 {"prop1":"prop1Data4","prop2":"prop2Data4","prop3":{"name":"Tom","age":"24","class":"graduate"},"prop4":"prop4Data4","prop5":"prop5Data4"}];

var plucked = function(o, wantedPropArray) {
    return _.reduce(wantedPropArray, function(acc, val){
        acc.push(_.deep(o,val));
        return acc;
    },[]);
}

var answer = _.map(objectArray, function(o){
    return plucked(o, ["prop1","prop2","prop3.name"]);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(answer));
```

Comment: the links you gave are good,but is it possible that i can get both the keys and values instead of only values, I mean basically i want the same object,but with only selected properties.

Comment: @bhargav,I tidied it up a bit more - the earlier solution was annoying me:)

Comment: i dont want to use the plucked solution, i want to get the sub properties as separate items,like [{"prop3.name":"tom","prop3.age":"24"},{"prop3.name":"cat","prop3.age":"25"}]

Comment: currently i am getting like this [{"prop3":{"name":"tom","age":"24"}},{"prop3":{"name":"cat","age":"25"}}]

Comment: so you want to flatten the structure?  you just want a flat array of objects containing the wanted properties?

Comment: yes i want a flattened structure.It would me easier for me to work on it.

Comment: @bhargav,updated my answer again to flatten the structure.  this is easier than preserving it :)

Comment: thanks Hogan, I have checked your code and is working as I need it to be. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Underscore.js, but you may try this code:

```
function pick(obj,list){
    var newObj={};
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        var str=list[i].split('.');
        var o=obj[str[0]];
        for(var j=1;j<str.length;j++){
            o=o[str[j]];
        }
        newObj[list[i]]=o;
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Underscore Deep Pick Plugin

I've created this plugin for underscore.js to help with problems like this.

[Deep Pick Pluging](https://github.com/mohsen1/deep_pick)

**Available at NPM and  Bower**

```
npm install deep_pick
bower install deep_pick
```

#### Example:

```
var input = {
  one: 1,
  two: true,
  three: 'Three',
  four: [1,2,3,4],
  five: {
    alpha: 1,
    beta: 2,
    gamma: 3,
    teta: {
        alef: 1,
        beh: 2,
        peh: 3
    }
  },
  answer: '42.00',
  description: 'This is an object.'
};


var schema = {
  one: true,
  three: true,
  five: {
    alpha: true,
    teta: {
      beh: true
    }
  }
};

deepPick(input, schema); // =>

{
  one: 1,
  three: "Three",
  five: {
    alpha: 1,
    teta: { 
      beh: 2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple gist exactly for this:
https://gist.github.com/peterslivka/9055188

```
_.mixin({ 
    pickDeep: function(obj) {
        var copy = {},
            keys = Array.prototype.concat.apply(Array.prototype, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.each(keys, function(key) {
            var subKeys = key.split('.');
            key = subKeys.shift();

            if (key in obj) {
                // pick nested properties
                if(subKeys.length>0) {
                    // extend property (if defined before)
                    if(copy[key]) {
                        _.extend(copy[key], _.pickDeep(obj[key], subKeys.join('.')));
                    }
                    else {
                        copy[key] = _.pickDeep(obj[key], subKeys.join('.'));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    copy[key] = obj[key];
                }
            }
        });

        return copy;
    }
});
```

You can find working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TFfHk/

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds there way here. The `_.pluck` function is what you want. Comes with underscore.

http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Answer (score 0):

lodash has some great methods for checking for and setting deep object properties: has, set, & get. You can use these functions to build up your own deepPick / deepPluck function. Below is an ES6 style function that builds on lodash and uses the built in Array.reduce method. Just a note that lodash uses the dot delimiter for nested properties.

```
/**
 * Deep pick / pluck properties.
 *
 * @param {object} the source object
 * @param {array[string]} the properties to pick
 */
function deepPick (source, props) {
  return props.reduce((result, key) => {
    const exists = lodash.has(source, key);

    if (exists) {
      lodash.set(result, key, lodash.get(source, key));
    }

    return result;
  }, {});
}
```